# Bug Tracker .NET - How to determine version from just the database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, schema, tracker

A recent blunder was made where the Bug Tracker .NET software was removed from our server;
now we don't have a backup of the installer that was used, only the database.  Is there a way to determine the version of Bug Tracker .NET supported by the database backup just based on the schema alone? without manually sifting through the different schema updates in each successive version? ...As far as I remember the schema is different enough that versions aren't fully backward/forward compatible hence I wish to find the version that was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the contents of the database [upgrade script](http://btnet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/btnet/upgrade.sql?revision=458&view=markup), it doesn't look like there is a version number stored in the database. This means that the only way to find which version you have is to backtrack through the upgrade script and see at which point you have the items in the script.

Comment: Yea, looks like it was backtracking as I thought and as you suggested...Thanks